# Inserting a description in mysql database with HTML entities - php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some descriptions, which looks like :

```
"Szukamy osoby chc\u0105cej pracowa\u0107 w zespole pe\u0142nym pasjonat\u00f3w. Poprzez rozwi\u0105zywanie zg\u0142aszanych do nas incydent\u00f3w kreujemy szcz\u0119\u015bcie u naszych wsp\u00f3\u0142pracownik\u00f3w :-). Nie ograniczamy si\u0119 do pojedynczej linii wsparcia. Bierzemy odpowiedzialno\u015b\u0107 E2E za nasze us\u0142ugi, serwery, sie\u0107\u2026.jak i za to, aby spotka\u0107 si\u0119 z u\u017cytkownikami, wys\u0142ucha\u0107 ich i wsp\u00f3lnie tworzy\u0107 najlepsze \u015brodowisko pracy.<\/p><p>Szukamy osoby, dla kt\u00f3rej wa\u017cna jest dobra atmosfera w pracy, chc\u0105cej wsp\u00f3\u0142tworzy\u0107 zesp\u00f3l na kt\u00f3ry mo\u017cna zawsze liczy\u0107."
```

As you can see this description contains, special characters like " \u00f3w " etc. When I try to insert it in the database, the sql insert query ignore the test after these characters wherever they are detected. How can I overcome this problem ? so that I can insert full texts.

I did something like !

```js
if (isset($_POST["add_jobdets"])) {

  $job_head = $_POST["job_head"];
  $job_details = html_entity_decode($_POST["job_details"]);
  $refNo = $_POST["refNo"];

  $jobs_dets = "INSERT INTO jobs_details VALUES (NULL,'$job_head','$job_details','$refNo','now()')";
  $con - > query($jobs_dets);


}
```

Even Tried this but Failed :

```js
if (isset($_POST["add_jobdets"])) {


  $jobs_dets = $con - > prepare("INSERT INTO jobs_details (jd_id,job_head,job_details,refNo,jd_time) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,'now()')");
  $jobs_dets - > bind_param('sss', $job_head, $job_details, $refNo);


  $job_head = $_POST["job_head"];
  $job_details = $_POST["job_details"];
  $refNo = $_POST["refNo"];



  $jobs_dets - > execute();

}
```

Comment: Look into prepared statements and bind variables, it has all sorts of benefits.

Comment: Mean ? @NigelRen

Comment: Have you tried searching for `php prepared statements`

Comment: Prepared statements docs are available at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Still have the same results @NigelRen

Comment: You wanted to insert the string `now()`  into `jd_time`?  I think I'd get rid of those single quotes.

Comment: No not that @mickmackusa. Its the string i have posted

Comment: If your question details are not accurate we cannot properly offer technical support.

Comment: @mickmackusa, if you go through the question, there I have mentioned that, the text after the special characters isn't stored in the database, above are the methods I have tried to insert them